# colon followed by a question

Tags: punctuation, colons, em-dashes

I did some search on the Internet but am unable to get clarity on this.

SET 1

Which of the following is correct?

A) Have you: Ever purchased a blue car? Ever visited Hong Kong? Ever gone on a long road trip?

B) Have you ever: purchased a blue car? visited Hong Kong? gone on a long road trip?

SET 2

I would also like to know if one needs to start a question after a colon with a capital

So if B is a better option, should I write 'Have you ever: Purchased a blue car? Visited Hong Kong? Gone on a long road trip?

Here there is more than 1 question but what if there is only one question after the colon? Do I still start with capitals? If I substitute colon with emdash does the same rule apply?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear: Are you quoting speech or writing an article, and in what context would you use your examples?

Comment: I am not quoting any speech.

Comment: The normal way to write this would be, "Have you ever purchased a blue car, visited Hong Kong, or gone on a long road trip?"  I agree with @Greybeard; we need some contextual reason for writing it with a colon.

Comment: @Manish "I am not quoting any speech" is not context. Please give context. For example, is this a multiple choice question?

Comment: The context is describing how people spend their money. Does this help?

Comment: you might call it a multiple choice question because more than one question can be applicable to a person.

Comment: @Manish They are multiple questions, not a multiple choice question. A multiple choice question is one where multiple potential answers are given only one of which is correct and the person taking the test has to select the correct one. For instance New Dehli is the capital of a) Pakistan b) India c) Bangladesh d) Sri Lanka. The correct answer is, of course, b).

Comment: Okay in that sense these are multiple questions and NOT multiple-choice questions.

Comment: The version using repeated _ever_'s is clunky, ugly. But colons are used to introduce all manner of strings, so firm rules are not going to be easy to dig out here, and they will be firm only in the opinion of the arrogator and fans. "Ever purchased a blue car?"  of course uses a conversational deletion (of auxiliary and subject) in a way quite acceptable in informal conversation. And acceptability here depends a lot on intended register. // I'd only ever use bullet points for this sort of thing. And modern practice certainly allows and probably prefers non-capitalisation for bulleted ...

Comment: strings that 'complete' a pre-bullet string. ... ... So (B) with bullets, non-capitalised, and three question marks is my firm favourite. I'd even drop the aging colon; the bulleting does the job quite well enough.